# Shape of a functional curve

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, graphing-functions

Can someone help me understand the shape and visual of the following functions:

> z = 36xy + 6( y - x ) - 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Please find the figure ploted using matlab with by simply varying x and y between -50 to 50 , equal interveld values of 100 points]

Please find the figure ploted using matlab with by simply varying x and y between -50 to 50 , equal interveld values of 100 points

Comment: Surface z=f(x,y) Monge form

Comment: Shouldn't the given function form a surface in 3D space rather than a curve?

Comment: You are right, if we have three variables, it should be a surface. But in above figure, the how the value of z varies when x and y are varied as mentioned above is plotted. z for all possible values of x and y will defintly form a surface. I posted it as Pranay wanted to see how the realtion looks like. The plot above is thus a slice of the surface.